# Simple and tested online regex containing regex delimiters does not work in C# code

Tags: c#, regex, windows-runtime

I have a regex like this:

```
name = dr-det-fb.ydp.eu/ebook/trunk/annotations/ctrl.php/api1751-4060-1193-0487
name = Regex.Replace(name, @"/\W/g", "");
```

This regex should replace "/", "-", "." with "".
But it doesn't, can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use regex delimiters:

```
name = Regex.Replace(name, @"\W", "");
```

In C#, you cannot use regex delimiters as the syntax to declare a regular expression is different from that of PHP, Perl or JavaScript or others that support `<action>/<pattern>(/<substitution>)/modifiers` regex declaration.

Just to avoid terminology confusion: *inline modifiers* (enforcing case-insensitive search, multiline, singleline, verbose and other modes) are certainly supported and can be used instead of the corresponding `RegexOptions` flags (though the number of possible `RegexOptions` flags is higher than that of inline modifiers). Still, *regex delimiters* do not influence the regex pattern at all, they are just part of declaration syntax, and do not impact the pattern itself. Say, they are just kind of substitutes for `;` or newline separating lines of code.

In C#, regex delimiters are not necessary and thus are not supported. Perl-style `s/\W//g` will be written as `var replaced = Regex.Replace(str, @"\W", string.Empty);`. And so on.