# C# Regex to match name and email from header

Tags: c#, regex

I have this Regex `@"/([^<]+)\s<(.*)>/"`  to match the name and email address from this string in C#:

```
John Doe <john.doe@gmail.com>
```

If I use `Regex.Match("John Doe <john.doe@gmail.com>", @"/([^<]+)\s<(.*)>/")`
what is the property of the result that returns both the name and email address in a collection?  I looked at Groups and Captures but neither returns the correct result.

Thanks.

Comment: C# doesn't need delimiters, remove the slashes.

Comment: Groups[1].Value is the name and Groups[2].Value is the email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the regex delimiters first. See [*this post explaining that issue*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560080/removing-all-non-word-characters-with-regex).

```
var match = Regex.Match("John Doe <john.doe@gmail.com>", @"([^<]+)\s<(.*)>");
```

Then, you can get the name and email via `match.Groups[1].Value` and `match.Groups[2].Value` respectively.

However, best is to use *named capture groups*:

```
var match = Regex.Match("John Doe <john.doe@gmail.com>", @"(?<name>[^<]+)\s<(?<mail>.*)>");
```

Then, you can access these values with `match.Groups["name"].Value` and `match.Groups["mail"].Value`.

And one more note on the pattern: if the email does not contain `>` nor `<`, I'd advise to also use a negated character class `[^<>]` there (matching any character but `<` and `>`):

```
(?<name>[^<]+)\s<(?<mail>[^<>]*)>
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative:

```
var m = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(@"John Doe <john.doe@gmail.com>");

Console.WriteLine(m.DisplayName);
Console.WriteLine(m.Address);
```

Comment: this is better way than regex

Comment: Thanks but would this cater for the different address formats in section 3.4 of RFC 2822?

Answer (score 0):

You can name your capturing groups:

```
(?<name>[^<]+)\s<(?<email>.*)>
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var match = Regex.Match("John Doe <john.doe@gmail.com>", @"(?<name>[^<]+)\s<(?<email>.*)>");

var name = match.Groups["name"];
var email = match.Groups["email"];
```