# How to find data in Mongo?

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb

The following algorithm find all documents that has a `<password>` entry in the `info`(string in XML format) field

```
db.getCollection('products').find({info:{$regex: /<password>/}});
```

but `passwordRecords` has 0 elements. Where did i make a mistake? Is it right way to update data in Mongo?

Comment: [Do not use regex delimiters in C# regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560080/removing-all-non-word-characters-with-regex), remove `/` from the C# regex pattern.

Comment: `var updatedString = Regex.Replace(r.info, @"/<(.*?password)>([^<]+)<\/(.*?password)", "<$1></$3>"); ` I also need to delete `/` from the beginning?

Comment: If the `/` is a slash that you want to match in the input string, no, it should be there then. What text are you trying to match? Your `<password>asdfghj</password>` can be matched with `(?s)<password>.*?</password>` and the updatedString can be hardcoded as `<password></password>`

Comment: Text where `info` have tags which name CONTAIN password (like `adminPassword`, `password`, `PasswordOfUser`)? Then I want to destroy values of all of this tags.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please give the answer to this question with final version (not in the comment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things to consider here.

- Do not use regex delimiters in C# regex (remove the outer `/.../`)
- If the `/` is a slash that you want to match in the input string, it should be in the pattern
- Your strings can be matched with `(?si)<([^\s<]*password[^\s<]*)>.*?</\1>` pattern and replaced with `<$1></$1>`: `Regex.Replace(r.info, @"(?si)<([^\s<]*password[^\s<]*)>.*?</\1>", "<$1></$1>");`

The pattern I suggest contains 2 things of interest:

- `(?si)` - DOTALL (Singleline) mode forcing a `.` to match a newline, too, and it also enables a case-insensitive match mode
- `([^\s<]*password[^\s<]*)` - captures a node name containing `password` (where the node has only a name, no attributes)
- `.*?` - matches any 0+ characters, as few as possible up to the next required subpattern
- `</\1>` - matches the closest corresponding tag matched with Group 1. Thus, *this is not going to match any nested tags.*

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fsi)%3C(%5B%5E%5Cs%3C%5D*password%5B%5E%5Cs%3C%5D*)%3E.*%3F%3C%2F%5C1%3E&i=%3Cjob%20xmlns%3Ai%3D%22...%22%20xmlns%3D%22...%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cpassword%3Easdfasdf%3C%2Fpassword%3E%0D%0A%3CadminPassword%3Easd%3C%2FadminPassword%3E%0D%0A...%3C%2Fjob%3E&r=%3C%241%3E%3C%2F%241%3E)

[image]

Comment: Why not "hardcode" it as `<password></password>`? Why do you need to use `Regex.Replace` if you are not accessing/using the text in-between (the innerHTML)?

Comment: As I said before, `r.Info` it's a big string(in xml format) and I need to replace(or change) value of tags like (`adminPassword`, `Password`, `passwordDB`) to `<adminPassword></adminPassword>` or `<Password></Password>`

Comment: Ah,  that's a different thing. Then you'd need to use [`Regex.Replace(r.info, @"(?s)<password>(.*?)</password>", "<adminPassword>$1</adminPassword>");`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)%3cpassword%3e(.*%3f)%3c%2fpassword%3e&i=%3cpassword%3etest%3c%2fpassword%3e&r=%3cadminPassword%3e%241%3c%2fadminPassword%3e) (see *Context* tab below).

Comment: Why do you harcode last parameter `<adminPassword>$1</adminPassword>`? I don't want to change tag `<password>asdfghj</password>` to `<adminPassword>$1</adminPassword>`

Comment: Because I thought you had them fixed. If these are not fixed tags, and they can just *contain* `password`, and they can be in different case, use [`Regex.Replace(r.info, @"(?si)<([^\s<]*password[^\s<]*)>(.*?)</\1>", "<$1>$2</$1>");`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fsi)%3c(%5b%5e%5cs%3c%5d*password%5b%5e%5cs%3c%5d*)%3e(.*%3f)%3c%2f%5c1%3e&i=%3cpassword%3etest%3c%2fpassword%3e%0d%0a%3cadminPassword%3etest%3c%2fadminPassword%3e&r=%3c%241%3e%242%3c%2f%241%3e)

Comment: Please, look at my updated question. I added one example

Comment: Is it correct regex `var regex = new Regex(@"(?s)<password>.*?</password>"); ` to find all info with tags like `adminPassword` or `password` etc ?

Comment: No, because `password` is hard-coded. Use the regex from the answer. `var regex = new Regex(@"(?si)<([^\s<]*password[^\s<]*)>.*?</\1>");`

Comment: The `<([^\s<]*password[^\s<]*)>` pattern cannot match just any tag with `p`. It can only match a tag that only has a name that contains a `password` character sequence.