# Regex to remove the third number and add commas

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following all number data:

```
4245 4 553.4 0242 4424.09 2 422404 5955 452
2234234.234 224 -345.25
2423 -234 64.69
```

I need to process each line individually.  I need to remove each third number and output as follows with commas:

Note the **space** only after each set:

```
4245,4, 0242,4424.09, 422404,5955
2234234.234,224
2423,-234
```

[With some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273706/regex-to-search-for-single-0s-and-add-commas), I was able to remove the third zero, but the third number can be any value now:

```
var input = "4245 4 0 242 4424.09 0 422404 5955 0";
var results = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?:\s+|^)0(\s+)|(\s+0)$|\s+", m =>
m.Groups[1].Success ? ", " :
m.Groups[2].Success ? "" : ",");
```

But cannot figure out how to remove the third number whether its zero or not.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to use regex?

Comment: Can't you just `String.Split` the line by space and remove the third item from the array?

Comment: I would like to see if it can be done with regex only without using string.Split and Linq.  This way I can compare it to the above Regex I already have.

Comment: Well, it is as easy as matching a decimal 3 times with capturing the first two occurrences and replacing with backreferences and adjusted punctuation: `(-?\d*\.?\d+) (-?\d*\.?\d+) -?\d*\.?\d+` -> `$1,$2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with `string.Split`, `string.Join`, and Linq.

```
var input = "4245 4 553.4 0242 4424.09 2 422404 5955 452";
var results = string.Join(
        ",",
        input.Split()
            .Select((s, i) => new { Value = s, Index = i + 1 })
            .Where(x => x.Index % 3 != 0)
            .Select(x => (x.Index % 3 == 1 && x.Index != 1 ? " " : string.Empty) + x.Value));
```

Will output

> 4245,4, 0242,4424.09, 422404,5955

Comment: Thank you Juharr!  One quick question, is there a way to maintain the commas in the following format: (space only after each set as seen in the output above) 4245,4, 0242,4424.09, 422404,5955

Comment: @RobertSmith Yeah, I've updated my answer to attempt to handle that as well.  It's a bit more messy as I'm just adding a space to the beginning of the next string after the one that was removed.

Comment: Juharr thank you, good job.  Would it be possible using an all regex solution? (without using split/linq)  I would like to compare it to the current all-regex above.  Thank you.

Comment: @RobertSmith The closest I can think of would be `Regex.Replace(input, @"(\S+)\s(\S+)\s\S+", "$1,$2,").TrimEnd(',');`.

Comment: Juharr thanks!  Great solution and great job, I marked your post as the answer.