# Removing possible file extension using RegEx during Argument passing?

Tags: regex, string, concatenation, parameter-passing, uipath

I recently started a internship where I get to code UiPath which is all new to me.
I'm wondering (and I hope I can phrase this correctly) if there is a way to remove the extension of a filename (if there is one) using regular expression, whilst passing the argument to it's function.

For ex.
I want to print my file "exampleFile.exe" as just "exampleFile" without actually changing the variable itself.

I cant figure out how to incorporate the RegEx I currently have to remove everything after the last "." found in a string. This is the expression I have: `/\.[^.]*$/`

I will also append a screenshot of the actual code I'm working with.

This code currently creates a file named "(Current file name).xml_metadata.xml" and I of course only want .xml at the very end

```
destinationFolderPath + "\" + CurrentFile.Name + "_metadata.xml"
```

[My Workspace, it's the Write to filename part which is insteresting here. It's opened in the editor on the side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ywbQ.png)

Hope any kind soul can help a struggling junior out!

Tried to remove the ending of a string and it just throws me an error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Regex.Replace(CurrentFile.Name, @"\.[^.]*$", "", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes that was a perfect solution to what I wanted! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `CurrentFile.Name` with

```cs
Regex.Replace(CurrentFile.Name, @"\.[^.]*$", "", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
```

Note that you [should not use regex delimiters in .NET patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31560118/3832970).

The `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` option allows for efficient pattern search from the end of the string.